# Getting A User Unhandled Exception at ''throw' statement in Registration Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I'm Creating custom Registration Page with Password Validation.Previously I tried to do this in JavaScript Approach those efforts failed.

For the front end validation I'm using Getter and setter  call Re_Enter_Password.Now I'm trying to add [NotMapped] attribute above that getter and setter.

Problem is When I try to insert registration details using view I'm Getting User Unhandled exception at throw statement in Controller Class.

I'm Using ADO.NET entity data model to access database.I'm not define field call Re_Enter_Password in database Table also.

This is My Controller Class : HECController.cs

```
using AFFEMS2_HEC;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AFFEMS2_HEC.Models;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web.Security;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using AFFEMS2_HEC.Filters;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace AFFEMS2_HEC.Controllers
{
    public class HECController : Controller
    {


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult HEI_Registration()
        {
            return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult HEI_Registration(AFFEMS2_HEC.Models.HEI_REG_TABLE user)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (var db = new AFFEMS2_HEC.Models.HEI_REG_DBEntities())
                    {
                        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
                        var encrypPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);
                        var newUser = db.HEI_REG_TABLE.Create();
                        newUser.HEI_ID = user.HEI_ID;                  
                        newUser.Username = user.Username;
                        newUser.Title = user.Title;
                        newUser.Firstname = user.Firstname;
                        newUser.Lastname = user.Lastname;
                        newUser.Email = user.Email;
                        newUser.Direct_Number = user.Direct_Number;
                        newUser.Mobile_Number = user.Mobile_Number;
                        newUser.Password = encrypPass;
                        newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

                        db.HEI_REG_TABLE.Add(newUser);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is not correct");
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {

                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                       eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);

                        //Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }


                throw ; // Add the original exception as the innerException
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        private bool IsValid(string email, string password)
        {
            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
            bool IsValid = false;

            using (var db = new AFFEMS2_HEC.Models.HEI_REG_DBEntities())
            {
                var user = db.HEI_REG_TABLE.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (user.Password == crypto.Compute(password, user.PasswordSalt))
                    {
                        IsValid = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return IsValid;
        }


    }

}
```

This is My Model Class : HEI_AccountModels.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AFFEMS2_HEC.Models

{
      public class HEI_REG_DBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public HEI_REG_DBEntities()
            : base("HEI_REG_DBEntities")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<HEI_REG_TABLE> HEI_REG_TABLE { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("HEI_REG_TABLE")]



      public class HEI_REG_TABLE
      {

          [Key]
          [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide ID", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
          public int HEI_ID { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
          public string Username { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Title", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
          public string Title { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide first name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
          public string Firstname { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide last name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
          public string Lastname { get; set; }

          [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})$",
          ErrorMessage = "Please provide valid email id")]
          public string Email { get; set; }

          public string Direct_Number { get; set; }

          public string Mobile_Number { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
          [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
          [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Password must be 5 char long.")]
          public string Password { get; set; }

          public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

          [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
          [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
          [NotMapped]
          public string Re_Enter_Password { get; set; }

      }

 }
```

This is my View: HEI_Registration.cshtml

```
   @model AFFEMS2_HEC.Models.HEI_REG_TABLE


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HEI_Registration";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Login_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/jscript"></script>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div style="border:solid 1px green">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }

               <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HEI_ID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HEI_ID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HEI_ID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lastname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Direct_Number)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Direct_Number)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direct_Number)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile_Number)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile_Number)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile_Number)
        </div>

        <div  class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div> 
            <div  class="editor-field">
              @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>

         <div  class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Re_Enter_Password)
        </div> 


            <div  class="editor-field">
              @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Re_Enter_Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Re_Enter_Password)
            </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Well in your `catch` you are `throw`ing the error, what are the details of that error?

Comment: @DavidG this is the error that I'm getting 
http://www.imagesup.net/?di=3141535142713

Comment: this is the error I'm getting 
http://www.imagesup.net/?di=3141535142713